# The delete view doesn't erase the correspondent object

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-2.2

I'm developing the backend of my personal blog and I've create a view that delete a single tag of the post.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from django.utils.text import slugify

from .forms import BlogTagForm
from .models import BlogTag

def deleteBlogTag(request, slug_tag):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tag = BlogTag.objects.get(slug_tag=slug_tag)
        tag.delete()
    return redirect('tag_list')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class BlogTag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(
        'Tag',
        max_length=50,
        help_text="Every key concept must be not longer then 50 characters",
        unique=True,
        )
    slug_tag = models.SlugField(
        'Slug',
        unique=True,
        help_text="Slug is a field in autocomplete mode, but if you want you can modify its contents",
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("single_blogtag", kwargs={"slug_tag": self.slug_tag})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['tag_name']
```

**urls.py**

```
path("tags/", views.listTagAdmin, name='tag_list_admin'),
path("create-tag/", views.createBlogTag, name='create_tag'),
path("update-tag/<str:slug_tag>/", views.updateBlogTag, name='update_tag'),
path("delete-tag/<str:slug_tag>/", views.deleteBlogTag, name='delete_tag'),
```

**tag_list.html**

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead class="bg-secondary text-white">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3"><h1 class="text-center"><strong>Tag List</strong></h1></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="1">Tag</th>
        <th colspan="1">Related Posts</th>
        <th class="text-center" colspan="1">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for tag in tag_list %}
      <tr>
        <td colspan="1">{{ tag.tag_name }}</td>
        <td colspan="1"><a href="{{ tag.get_absolute_url }}">{{ tag.tag_blogpost.count }}</a></td>
        <td colspan="1">

          <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm mx-1" href="{% url 'update_tag' slug_tag=tag.slug_tag %}">Update</a>

            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mx-1" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete</button>

            <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h2 class="modal-title text-center" id="deleteModalLabel">Delete Request</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <h3>Are you sure to delete this tag?</h3>
                    <h1 class="py-4"><em><strong>{{ tag.tag_name }}</strong></em></h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">No, don't do this</button>
                    <form action="{% url 'delete_tag' slug_tag=tag.slug_tag %}" method="POST">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit" name="button">Yes, delete it</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </td>
      </tr>

      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

The problem is that it's not possible to delete every single objects of the list but only the first object. Even if I try to delete the last object I delete the first object instead of the last.

Where I've wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your modal forms are named *the same*, hence it will pick one. If it searches for a specific `id`, it will pick one. In order to solve this, you should give your `modal`s different `id`s:

```
    <tbody>
      {% for tag in tag_list %}
      <tr>
        <td colspan="1">{{ tag.tag_name }}</td>
        <td colspan="1"><a href="{{ tag.get_absolute_url }}">{{ tag.tag_blogpost.count }}</a></td>
        <td colspan="1">

          <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm mx-1" href="{% url 'update_tag' slug_tag=tag.slug_tag %}">Update</a>

            <button data-target="#deleteModal{{ tag.pk }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mx-1" type="button" data-toggle="modal">Delete</button>

            <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal{{ tag.pk }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h2 class="modal-title text-center" id="deleteModalLabel">Delete Request</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <h3>Are you sure to delete this tag?</h3>
                    <h1 class="py-4"><em><strong>{{ tag.tag_name }}</strong></em></h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">No, don't do this</button>
                    <form action="{% url 'delete_tag' slug_tag=tag.slug_tag %}" method="POST">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit" name="button">Yes, delete it</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

So here we added a suffix to the `id` of the `<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal{{ tag.pk }}" ...>`, and used the same `id` in the `<button target="#deleteModal{{ tag.pk }}" ...>`.